# XMonad: how to show the currently visible workspace on xmobar when using multiple screens?

Tags: xmonad, xmobar

I'm using XMonad in a setup with multiple physical screens.

I would like each of the physical screens to have an instance of `xmobar` which
shows which workspace is visible on that particular screen, regardless of whether
that workspace is "current"/"active" or not.

E.g.

```
+--------------+  +--------------+                                                      
|              |  |              |                                                      
|              |  |              |                                                      
|              |  |              |                                                      
|              |  |              |                                                      
+--------------+  +--------------+                                                      
|Workspace 3   |  |Workspace 5   |                                                      
+--------------+  +--------------+
```

My current (minimized for clarity) `xmonad.hs` is below.

```
import XMonad                                                                           
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders                                                          
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks                                                         
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog                                                          
import XMonad.Util.Run                                                                  
import XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens                                                 
                                                                                        
main = do                                                                               
    n <- countScreens                                                                   
    xmprocs <- mapM (\i -> spawnPipe $ "xmobar" ++ " -x " ++ show i) [0..n-1]           
                                                                                        
    xmonad $ docks def                                                                  
        { layoutHook = avoidStruts $ smartBorders $ layoutHook defaultConfig            
        , logHook = mapM_ (\xmobarPipe -> dynamicLogWithPP $ def                        
            { ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmobarPipe                                           
            , ppCurrent = \s -> s                                                       
            , ppVisible = \s -> ""                                                      
            , ppHidden = \s -> ""                                                       
            , ppLayout = \s -> ""                                                       
            , ppTitle = \s -> ""                                                        
            }) xmprocs                                                                  
        }
```

That is, I managed to spawn 2 instances of xmobar, one for each screen. However it simply shows the currently active Workspace (across screens) on both screens' xmobar. E.g. it would show:

```
+--------------+  +--------------+                                                      
|              |  |              |                                                      
|              |  |              |                                                      
|              |  |              |                                                      
|              |  |              |                                                      
+--------------+  +--------------+                                                      
|Workspace 3   |  |Workspace 3   |                                                      
+--------------+  +--------------+
```

Now, how do I achieve what I actually want?

I *think* the configuration here
https://github.com/nwf/xconfig/blob/208e6d6ce48fba45ec30bb1df1389f9ff2263edd/xmonad/lib/XMonad/Actions/XMobars.hs#L163
might contain hints to the answer but I'm not proficient enough in Haskell to
work back from that example to something minimal that I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import GHC.IO.Handle.Types (Handle)

import XMonad (MonadIO, WorkspaceId, Layout, Window, ScreenId, ScreenDetail, WindowSet, layoutHook, logHook, X, io, ScreenId(..), gets, windowset, xmonad)
import Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86 (xF86XK_MonBrightnessUp, xF86XK_MonBrightnessDown)
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders (smartBorders)
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks (docks, avoidStruts)
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog (def)
import XMonad.Util.Run (spawnPipe, hPutStrLn)
import XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens (countScreens)
import XMonad.StackSet (current, screen, visible, Screen, workspace, tag)

spawnXMobar :: MonadIO m => Int -> m (Int, Handle)
spawnXMobar i = (spawnPipe $ "xmobar" ++ " -x " ++ show i) >>= (\handle -> return (i, handle))

spawnXMobars :: MonadIO m => Int -> m [(Int, Handle)]
spawnXMobars n = mapM spawnXMobar [0..n-1]

type ScreenFoo = Screen WorkspaceId (Layout Window) Window ScreenId ScreenDetail

visibleScreens :: WindowSet -> [ScreenFoo]
visibleScreens cws = ([current cws]) ++ (visible cws)

joinToString :: [String] -> String
joinToString workspaceIds = foldl (++) "" workspaceIds

myLogHookForPipe :: WindowSet -> (Int, Handle) -> X ()
myLogHookForPipe currentWindowSet (i, xmobarPipe) =
    io $ hPutStrLn xmobarPipe $ -- write to pipe and lift to XMonad
    joinToString $ map (tag . workspace) $  -- extract workspace names and join into a single string
    filter ((==) (S i) . screen) $  -- filter to this xmobar's screen only
    visibleScreens currentWindowSet  -- get list of all visible screens

myLogHook :: [(Int, Handle)] -> X ()
myLogHook xmobarPipes = do
    currentWindowSet <- gets windowset
    mapM_ (myLogHookForPipe currentWindowSet) xmobarPipes

main = do
    n <- countScreens
    xmobarPipes <- spawnXMobars n

    xmonad $ docks def
        { layoutHook = avoidStruts $ smartBorders $ layoutHook def
        , logHook = myLogHook xmobarPipes
        }
```